syslog in logback + springboot doesnt't work for me
const Syslog = require('simple-syslog-server') ;
 
// Create our syslog server with the given transport
const options = {} ;
const address = 'localhost' ; // Any
const port = 514 ;
const listen = {host: address, port: port} ;
var server = Syslog.TCP(options) ;
 
server.on('msg', data => {
    console.log('message received from %s:%i\n%o\n', data.address, data.port, data) ;
})
.listen(listen)
.then(() => {
    console.log(`Now listening on: ${address}:${port}`) ;
}) ;
 

This is the syslog server using port 514
<configuration>

    <!-- Console Appender -->
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Syslog Appender -->
    <appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
        <syslogHost>localhost</syslogHost> <!-- Syslog server hostname or IP address -->
        <port>514</port> <!-- Syslog server port -->
        <facility>LOCAL0</facility> <!-- Syslog facility -->
        <suffixPattern>[%thread] %logger %msg</suffixPattern>
    </appender>

    <!-- Set the default logging level -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" />
    </root>

</configuration>

This is logback.xml
I just tried to get log the below
        logger.info("test test");
        logger.info("test test");
        logger.info("test test");
        logger.info("test test");
        logger.info("test test");

console log shows the log, but the syslog server doesn't show anything.. The app is running on windows.
Does anyone know why...?
syslog server should show the output of the logs
